# Warning "Instance method '-methodname' not found (return type defaults to 'id')" while it exist and works fine

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I found some similar questions belonging this warning, but they are not answered or not really precisely asked.

My AppDelegate has an instance variable named **AppModel* iVarModel**.
The App Delegate has a declared Property and meanwhile even a separate getter for it, like:

**AppDelegate.h**

```
AppModel* iVarModel;    

@property (nonatomic, retain) AppModel* iVarModel;  

- (AppModel*) getAppModel;
```

**AppDelegate.m**

```
@synthesize iVarModel;  

- (AppModel*) getAppModel {
  return iVarModel;
}
```

In a different class
I like to access this via the singleton application object:

**FarFarAwayClass.h**

```
import "AppDelegate.h"
...
```

**FarFarAwayClass.m**

```
//get a pointer to the application object
UIApplication* thisApp = [UIApplication sharedApplication];

// get a pointer to the application's delegate
id<UIApplicationDelegate> theDelegateObject = [thisApp delegate];


// >(1)< access AppModel's property iVarModel
AppModel* iVarModel_byProp = [theDelegateObject iVarModel];

// >(2)< access AppModel's iVarModel via getter
AppModel* iVarModel_byGet = [theDelegateObject getAppModel];
```

Independently how I try to access it >(1)< or >(2)< it works, but I do get this warning:

```
Instance method '-iVarModel' not found (return type defaults to 'id')
Instance method '-getAppModel' not found (return type defaults to 'id')
```

Why does the compiler thinks those methods would not exist, even while he can use them correctly?

By the way it does make no difference if I skip the getter or the declared property I do always get this warning.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler is warning you because you told the compiler this local variable 'theDelegateObject' is of type 'id'. In other words, you said it is "some NSObject that implements the UIApplicationDelegate protocol". You didn't say anything about it being an instance of your particular AppDelegate class.

If you do this instead the compiler will know what you're doing:

```
MyAppDelegate* theDelegateObject = (MyAppDelegate*) [thisApp delegate];
```

This gives the compiler the type information it needs to know that this object should respond to your own methods you wrote.

As for why this works fine as is at runtime, remember message passing is dynamic, the compiler doesn't need to bind to this method at compile time. It just dutifully writes the method call you asked for. At runtime, this works out because the application's delegate turns out to be an actual instance of your AppDelegate class.

Hope that makes sense?

Comment: Clearly explained, I do understand it.
But it isn't a "particular AppDelegateClass". The method **delegate** returns  **id<UIApplicationDelegate>. Like you say a object adopting the <UIApplicationDelegate>-Protocol. 
If I cast to **id<UIApplicationDelegate> theDelegate = (id<UIApplicationDelegate>)[thisApp delegate]** the warning from the original questions stays on.

I found the (at least a) solution by (as far as I think) providing less information to the compiler while using **id** as return type.
 
        id theDelegate = [thisApp delegate];


See my answer below …

Comment: Your object is of your particular class. That's why you expect to be able to access that property of that particular class. See my comment to your answer. I would argue that's not a good way to solve this at all.

Comment: this is not the right answer. "not found" only occurs when a declaration is missing. i.e. he didn't import the header

Comment: @noone, this answer (above) is correct.  You have declared theDelegateObject as type id<UIApplicationDelegate>, and that type does NOT have an iVarModel or getAppModel method.  Thus the warning.  To fix it, you will have to declare it as type AppDelegate*, which is certainly the class you have in mind.  (And yes, you will need to typecast the assignment to it, since the delegate method's return type is more general.)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue to this recently and discovered that (goodness knows how) my project had duplicate AppDelegate.h and AppDelegate.m files in different places. I was editing one and the compiler was using the other which meant it couldn't see the instance methods I was adding! Removing the duplicate files resolved the issue.

Comment: Hmm my Project Navigator shows just one **<AppName>Delegate.[h|m]**.
  
Thought it might be a double include/import of **<AppName>Delegate.h** anywhere. A complete full text search found one single match in **<AppName>Delegate.m** right where it should be.

  
Nice idea but finally not the solution yet. :-(

Comment: Even if you are **forgotten to import** that category or class. this shows the same Warning “Instance method '-methodname' not found (return type defaults to 'id')”

Answer (score 0):

This error can occure if the instanciation of your class have the same name that the class itself

```
MyClassSample *MyClassSample = [[MyClassSample alloc] init];
```

To solve this you can simply modify the instanciation name ( M -> m )

```
MyClassSample *myClassSample = [[MyClassSample alloc] init];
```

Answer (score -2):

I found it on my own. To let you know it and let others find the solution here it is:

As trying to be precisely I used:

**FarFarAwayClass.m** (1st version)

```
id<UIApplicationDelegate> theDelegateObject = [thisApp delegate];
```

Means providing the compiler with the information "I need a object here which adopts the protocol UIApplicationDelegate". But this seems to confuse the compiler. Just using **id** avoids the warning.

**FarFarAwayClass.m** (2nd version - to get rid of the warning named in original question)

```
id theDelegateObject = [thisApp delegate];
```

All warnings are gone :-)

Comment: Ooh, no, this is not the way you want to handle this. The compiler is not confused. The compilers relax these warnings when the type is just id. But if you start doing that everywhere, you'll lose warnings that you DO want. Like, try misspelling a method name now. What you're doing now is keeping the compiler in the dark, the right answer is to give the compiler more information, not less.

Comment: You have an object that implements the UIApplicationDelegate protocol.  You need to figure out why the compiler doesn't think your object will respond to the "delegate" message, don't just stifle the error.